# Align and scale images in bootstrap over full with of DIV

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to insert 8 images and a button in a div in a bootstrap Joomla template. I need the images to be vertically aligned in the centre and horizontally evenly aligned over the with in all responsive views (mobile, tablet, small laptop, large screen with max 1920px of with). This is my test website:

[webdisenjo.nl](https://www.webdisenjo.nl) and the logo div is "moduletable logos_home"

I am struggling with what the with of the image should be and how to place them in the div.

Now, I have tried this class.
`<div class="logo-inline-div"><img src="images/logo/Logo_3WO.png" /></div>`

but it does not work well.

I have also tried this class

`<div class="row"><div class="col-8"></div></div>`

```
.col-8{width: 10%;}
```

But that also does not work.

Comment: can you show us what exactly you want may be a mockup would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleanup your code a bit and added class `clients-section`

so just try to add below html inside of your `logos_home` and use this css and it would look like this

[image]

```
<div class="custom logos_home">
   <div class="row clients-section">
      <div class=""><img src="/images/logo/Logo_3WO.png" alt="pubblikvos Logo_3WO"></div>
      <div class=""><img src="/images/logo/Logo_ACP.png" alt="pubblikvos Logo_ACP"></div>
      <div class=""><img src="/images/logo/Logo_Amvest.png" alt="pubblikvos Logo_Amvest"></div>
      <div class=""><img src="/images/logo/Logo_CBRE.png" alt="pubblikvos Logo_CBRE.png"></div>
      <div class=""><img src="/images/logo/Logo_Fine-Hotels-Suites.png" alt="pubblikvos Logo_Fine-Hotels-Suites"></div>
      <div class=""><img src="/images/logo/Logo_Greystar.png" alt="pubblikvos Logo_Greystar"></div>
      <div class=""><img src="/images/logo/Logo_MiCompany.png" alt="pubblikvos Logo_MiCompany"></div>
      <div class=""><img src="/images/logo/logo_NS.png" alt="pubblikvos logo_NS"></div>
   </div>
   <div><a class="knop_alle-clienten" href="/nl/projecten">Alle clienten</a></div>
</div>



.clients-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.logos_home {
    text-align: center;
}

a.knop_alle-clienten {
    margin: 40px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of photos are in one div and you want them to be always same size whenever you want to resize the screen, you need either to have those images to be same size or you have to force them to be same size.
you can easily wrap the images with a div then give it a `display:flex`; and `flex-wrap:wrap`;
then give the images some width: for example if you want 4 photos per row give each image width of 25%.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.logo-inline-div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px 24px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 12.4%;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .col-1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  div.logo-inline-div {
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="EightImages.css" />
    <link rel="images" href="images" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426__340.jpg"/>
            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426__340.jpg" />
            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426__340.jpg"/>

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426__340.jpg" />

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426__340.jpg" />

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426__340.jpg" />

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426__340.jpg"/>

            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-1">
          <div class="logo-inline-div">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426__340.jpg"/>
            <label>Build an Empire</label>
            <p>
              Test
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```